# how to add tabs into tabcontrol in mfc dialog based application and display the tabs in middle of the dialog

Tags: mfc, dialog, tabcontrol

I am designing a desktop application in mfc dialog based application. How to use the tabcontrol and how to add controls inside each tab after it creation. please help me out, I'm new to this.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have experience with other development environments (like C++ Builder, VB, Delphi, .Net, etc) you would be very disappointed to find that the tab control in MFC is merely it is, just the tab control. It does not behave like a set of "Panels". What it means is that if you put other controls on your dialog they will belong to the dialog, but not to the "pages" of the tab control (even if you make your tab control as big as the dialog).

If you have just a few controls on "each page", you can get away with putting them all on the dialog and just hide/show them when you switch between the tab pages.

If the number of controls is big, you may need to create separate dialogs in the resource that will represent each of your pages. Then, you would create "child" sub-dialogs of your main dialog with the tab control and will be hiding/showing the whole sub-dialogs

Comment: there are many articles on codeproject.com. I recommend to start with http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1383/CTabCtrlSSL-An-easy-to-use-flexible-extended-tab-c and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8565/Simple-Tab-Control-For-Visual-C. But don't stop on these two, there are just too many of them to list them all here